# Multiple count statements/conditions

Tags: sql, count

I have the following columns as follows:

```
Product_ID,sale_price,sale_count,sale_state
9923842,49.99,329,CA
2940820,55.25,430,WA
2039483,32.45,23,OR
9348234,55.02,26,NY
1948134,99.42,200,VA
3948579,43.49,994,MA
2034209,934.3,430,FL
```

I'm trying to find the counts by Coast of states that have a sale_count of > 100  based on West Coast vs East Coast (CA and OR are West Coast, NY and MA are on the East and so on).
So the result would look like:

```
coast,count,total_count
East,3,4
West,2,3
```

... where total_count is the total number of states on that coast irrespective of the sale counts

The only way I can think of is to create a table with state/coast mapping and then use that as a reference.
Is there a better way without having to resort to temp tables?

This is currently being done in MySQL but I'd like a platform agnostic solution as this may be ported to another platform soon.

Comment: What is the `total_count`? Number of products regardless of a  `sale_count > 100`?

Comment: Right, what is count vs. total count?

Comment: Yes, total_count is irrespective of sale_count>100 - edited the question

Comment: Thanks, updated my query below

Answer (score 0):

Here's a standard ANSI way to do it, that should work I hope

```
    SELECT 'East' AS Coast, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN sale_count > 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt, 
           COUNT(*) AS total_count 
    FROM table 
    WHERE sale_state IN ('NY','MA')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'West' AS Coast, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN sale_count > 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt, 
           COUNT(*) AS total_count 
    FROM table 
    WHERE sale_state IN ('CA','OR')
```

I am from EU so I let you complete the states' lists...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This one contains count and total_count as described in your comment above

```
SELECT coast, SUM(sale_cnt) AS count, COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM T LEFT JOIN
(SELECT sale_state,
CASE 
WHEN sale_state IN ('CA','WA','OR') THEN 'West'
WHEN sale_state IN ('NY','VA','MA','FL') THEN 'East' END AS coast,
CASE
WHEN sale_count > 100 THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS sale_cnt
FROM T) C
ON T.sale_state = C.sale_state
GROUP BY coast
```

Comment: The issue with that approach is that it wont work on many RDBMS because its not ANSI compliant to use an aliased column in the GROUP BY clause ;)